# Why is this SQL Query saying "Command not properly ended" when I try to execute it?

Tags: mysql

Why is this SQL Query saying "Command not properly ended" when I try to execute it?

```
     SELECT
"VENDER"."ALIAS",
"VENDERINVOICE"."INVOICENO", 
"VENDERINVOICE"."INVDATE", 
"VENDERINVOICE"."AMOUNT", 
"PO"."PONUMBER",
"VENDERINVOICE"."POSTDATE" AS "PAY DATE",
"VENDERINVOICE"."POSTDATE" AS "DISTRIBUTION",
"PO"."CALLSLIPNO",
case PO.SUBIND
        when 'Y' then 'SU'
        when 'N' then 'MA'
    end as SMCOST,
"PO"."JOBTYPEID",
"VENDERINVOICE"."NET_AMOUNT",
(("TAXCODE"."TAXRATE" + 5)*.01)*"VENDERINVOICE"."NET_AMOUNT" - "VENDERINVOICE"."SALES_TAX_AMOUNT" "ACCRUE AMMOUNT",
"PO"."TAXCODE"

 FROM   
    ((("STARPO"."VENDERPOITEM" "VENDERPOITEM" INNER JOIN "STARPO"."PO" "PO" ON "VENDERPOITEM"."PO_KEY"="PO"."PO_KEY") INNER JOIN "STARPO"."VENDERINVOICE" 

"VENDERINVOICE" ON "VENDERPOITEM"."VENDERINVOICE_KEY"="VENDERINVOICE"."VENDERINVOICE_KEY") INNER JOIN "STARPO"."VENDER" "VENDER" ON 

"VENDERINVOICE"."VENDER_KEY"="VENDER"."VENDER_KEY") INNER JOIN "STARPO"."TAXCODE" "TAXCODE" ON "PO"."TAXCODE"="TAXCODE"."TAXCODE"

    GROUP BY
 "VENDER"."ALIAS",
"VENDERINVOICE"."INVOICENO", 
 "VENDERINVOICE"."INVDATE", 
 "VENDERINVOICE"."AMOUNT", 
 "PO"."PONUMBER",
 "VENDERINVOICE"."POSTDATE" AS "PAY DATE",
 "VENDERINVOICE"."POSTDATE" AS "DISTRIBUTION"

 WHERE  
    "VENDERINVOICE"."INVDATE">= :START_DATE
     AND "VENDERINVOICE"."INVDATE" <= :END_DATE
     AND "PO"."PONUMBER" <> 100256
```

Comment: `where` should come before `group by`....

Comment: The syntax seems invalid with all these quotes around all table names and field names.

Comment: I know "to each their own" but doesn't all that uppercase just fry out your eyes by 2pm?

Comment: What sgeddes said; and I pretty sure `AS` is not allowed in `GROUP BY` clauses.

Comment: @Drew Don't you have armored eyes after so much time on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @Jocelyn I do yes. Maybe it is CobolSql we are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some of the comments, and trying to format in a bit more standard way (I know there are many standards...).

- Removed quotes
- Moved WHERE to the correct place
- Removed unnecessary parenthesis from JOINs (were they necessary?)
- Moved AS to SELECT clause

Try this:

```
SELECT
VENDER.ALIAS,
VENDERINVOICE.INVOICENO, 
VENDERINVOICE.INVDATE, 
VENDERINVOICE.AMOUNT, 
PO.PONUMBER,
VENDERINVOICE.POSTDATE AS PAY DATE,
VENDERINVOICE.POSTDATE AS DISTRIBUTION,
PO.CALLSLIPNO,
case PO.SUBIND
        when 'Y' then 'SU'
        when 'N' then 'MA'
    end as SMCOST,
PO.JOBTYPEID,
VENDERINVOICE.NET_AMOUNT,
((TAXCODE.TAXRATE + 5)*.01)*VENDERINVOICE.NET_AMOUNT - VENDERINVOICE.SALES_TAX_AMOUNT ACCRUE AMMOUNT,
PO.TAXCODE

 FROM STARPO.VENDERPOITEM VENDERPOITEM 
 INNER JOIN STARPO.PO PO 
    ON VENDERPOITEM.PO_KEY = PO.PO_KEY
 INNER JOIN STARPO.VENDERINVOICE VENDERINVOICE 
    ON VENDERPOITEM.VENDERINVOICE_KEY = VENDERINVOICE.VENDERINVOICE_KEY
 INNER JOIN STARPO.VENDER VENDER 
    ON VENDERINVOICE.VENDER_KEY = VENDER.VENDER_KEY
 INNER JOIN STARPO.TAXCODE TAXCODE 
    ON PO.TAXCODE=TAXCODE.TAXCODE

 WHERE VENDERINVOICE.INVDATE >= :START_DATE
    AND VENDERINVOICE.INVDATE <= :END_DATE
    AND PO.PONUMBER <> 100256

 GROUP BY
     VENDER.ALIAS,
     VENDERINVOICE.INVOICENO, 
     VENDERINVOICE.INVDATE, 
     VENDERINVOICE.AMOUNT, 
     PO.PONUMBER,
     VENDERINVOICE.POSTDATE
```